# How to set QTip to always show tooltips in Cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, qtip2

I'm looking for a way of getting QTip to concurrently display tooltips for each node in a Cytoscape.js graph, such that they are always displayed and anchored to the nodes in the graph without the user having to click or mouseover the node.

I got close with the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            cy.nodes().qtip({
                content: function(){ return 'Station: ' + this.id() +
                                       '</br> Next Train: ' + this.data('nextTrain') +
                                       '</br> Connections: ' + this.degree();
                        },
                hide: false,
                show: {
                    when: false,
                    ready: true
                 }
            })
        })
```

The above code displays tooltips on $(document).ready, but they are all located at one node in the Cytoscape graph and they disappear when I zoom in or pan at all.

The goal is to have tooltips anchored to each node in my graph such that when I zoom in and pan around they remain fixed to that node. I'm not sure if there is an easier way to do this just using Cytoscape (i.e., multi-feature labelling).

I'm using Qtip2, jQuery-2.0.3 and the most recent release of cytoscape.js

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** If you want to create these elements automatically, use a function and a loop to iterate over cy.nodes():

```
var makeTippy = function (nodeTemp, node) {
    return tippy(node.popperRef(), {
        html: (function () {
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            // do things in div
            return div;
        })(),
        trigger: 'manual',
        arrow: true,
        placement: 'right',
        hideOnClick: false,
        multiple: true,
        sticky: true
    }).tooltips[0];
};
var nodes = cy.nodes();
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var tippy = makeTippy(nodes[i]);
    tippy.show();
}
```

If you want a sticky qTip, I would instead recommend the cytoscape extension for **popper.js** and specificly the **tippy version** (sticky divs):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    style: [{
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
          'content': 'data(id)'
        }
      },
      {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
          'curve-style': 'bezier',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
        }
      }
    ],
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: 'a'
          }
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'b'
          }
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          source: 'a',
          target: 'b'
        }
      }]
    },
    layout: {
      name: 'grid'
    }
  });
  var a = cy.getElementById('a');
  var b = cy.getElementById('b');
  var makeTippy = function(node, text) {
    return tippy(node.popperRef(), {
      html: (function() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = text;
        return div;
      })(),
      trigger: 'manual',
      arrow: true,
      placement: 'bottom',
      hideOnClick: false,
      multiple: true,
      sticky: true
    }).tooltips[0];
  };
  var tippyA = makeTippy(a, 'foo');
  tippyA.show();
  var tippyB = makeTippy(b, 'bar');
  tippyB.show();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica neue, helvetica, liberation sans, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px
}

#cy {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* makes sticky faster; disable if you want animated tippies */

.tippy-popper {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Tippy > qTip</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js"></script>
  <script src="cytoscape-popper.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@2.0.9/dist/tippy.all.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@2.0.9/dist/tippy.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cytoscape-popper@1.0.2/cytoscape-popper.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape-popper tippy demo</h1>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I think popper is just easier to handle when having the divs 'stick around'

Comment: Popper does seem to be superior to QTip. Is it possible in Popper to automatically create a tooltip for each element in the cytoscape graph without having to manually trigger TippyA, TippyB, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late edit, i added that functionality to my answer :)  Thanks for the hint!